# How do I resend the invitation email for testflight for internal tester?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I am a developer on our Apple Developer account.

I added myself to testflight as an internal tester and redeemed my code and installed.

I then switched Apple ID on my device and installed a different app for a completely different developer account through testflight.

I then switched back to my first Apple ID. Now when I go into the testflight app, it says I have no apps installed. I don't have my original redeem code either (but I think that is one time use anyways).

When I go to app store connect, and navigate to the app testflight page, it shows my account as "Installed" even though it is not. Some internal testers have "resend invite" option next to their name, but there is not that option next to my account. I can remove my account as a tester, and then add it again, but it makes no difference. As soon as I add myself back, it immediately goes back to showing "installed" again.

I have tried reinstalling testflight and that made no difference.

How do I get myself a new redeem code for this app?

Comment: Did you relogin to the App Store account or the iCloud account?

Comment: Its the same account.

Comment: Yes, but there are separate logins on the device. As soon as I log in with my Apple ID into the App Store on a new device TestFlight shows me my available apps. There is no way to resend a code

Comment: My app store automatically inherited the login I set in system settings for icloud. IN short, yes they both match.

Comment: I'm not sure.  I've never had a problem with TestFlight showing my registered apps.  Note that the TestFlight redemption is linked to the App Store account that was logged in when you redeemed the code, not the email address that the invitation was sent to;  Is it possible that you have linked the code to a different Apple ID?

Comment: @Scorb Did you resolve your problem ? 
I'm not changing Apple Id's. I just removed the App from my iPad. The TestFlight App shows status "Tester Removed". In App Store Connect, I removed my account from the Testing group and added it back but like you it just keeps saying "Installed" with no option to send an invite. I've used this method of removing and adding the account back numerous times in the past and it always worked. The behaviour has definitely changed.

Comment: Same issue there

Comment: What is the fix for this issue? Running into this with a tester as well

Comment: Here is what worked for me.  It's crazy but it worked. (1) Delete the user from the internal group. (2) Add the user to an external group. (3) Delete user from external group. (4) Add user to the internal group. Resend Invite button should now be available in the status column.

Answer (score 41):

Go AppStoreConnect > [Your App] > Testflight, go to All Testers, under General information, on the Side menu [All testers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiF5R.png)

Then remove the email. Then go to internal Testing and add it again.

Comment: Worked for me. What's extra interesting is that you must do the removal from "All Testers." When I did the removal from "Internal Testing" it did not work.

Comment: Same here. That is the working solution

Comment: This works in 2023.

Comment: this works but I get "Invitation revoked or invalid" when trying to redeem the code :(

Comment: This needs more upvotes, works like a charm, the tester must be removed from 'All' first...great design from Apple yet again

Answer (score 3):

First delete Apple ID X from list of INTERNAL testers, then add Apple ID X to list of EXTERNAL testers:
[image]
Then remove APPLE ID X from list of EXTERNAL testers:
[image]
Finally add APPLE ID to list of INTERNAL testers.

User should receive an email with invitation and in case it didn't work try Resend option.

This issue probably happens when an int. tester becomes an ext. tester by using invitation link.

Answer (score -3):

Update: THIS DOES NOT WORK ANYMORE.

Go to AppStoreConnect remove & add your account again. That will send you a new invite.

Use ANY Apple ID to accept/redeem invite. Apple ID you use on that device So you don't have to keep switching Apple ID.

Let say you have invited first@company.com and accepted/redeemed with last@personal.com.

ASC Still considers that's invite used for first@company.com. Removing first@company.com from ASC will remove last@personal.com from getting any new builds.

So you don't need to keep switching accounts. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Already done 10 times. No invite received.

Comment: Yeah if an old device was connected to the email account there is no way from the portal to move it to a new device.  Connect just still thinks that email is using test flight on that old device and it will not resend the invite.  It just basically discovers the old device and says the app is already installed. I have found no way around this.